# Accessing SQL Server remotely and generate report

Tags: c#

Actually I am bit of confused right now and need some guidance. I have been offer a project to create web portal to generate report. Scenario is something like this,

Client has a business and he need to check the report of hourly sale. What should I do, should I put the SQL Server online or is there any other way to excess server database remotely. I have no experience in creating web portal, how should I start doing it.

Can anyone guide me in proper manner? I have experience in C#.NET using Visual Studio 2010.

Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend adding more detail to your question before the SO police come down on you. Like where is the data coming from? Is the web portal just for accessing reports? Will it also be used to interface with the data that the report uses? Depending on your situation you might benefit from downloading an open source CMS.

Comment: Sorry for that. I can give you a proper example - if you had a grocerry store and you want to check the daily sale, add inventory and so on. Database is on server side, might be at your store then what would you do to generate report, add item and how to access server database to get all the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This suggestion is without completely understanding your situation but...

There is an open source package called **nopcommerce** which has an inventory system, sales and other canned reports and a basic CMS built in.

It also includes all source code in C# and works with SQL Server.

It's generic enough to use for most retail scenarios and going this route will save you TONS of time trying to start from scratch.

I would think you could just download, install and customize and get 95% of everything  you need from it.